# how to pass the variables to a bash file as json file( list of dict)

Tags: arrays, list, shell, dictionary

I am trying to pull docker images from multiple repository using same bash script. I have to run the script N times till processing all variables. Sample variable file is mentioned below,

```
[
{
"ECR_REPO_URL":"111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
"ECR_REPO_NAME":"test-ecr-repo",
"REGION":"us-east-1",
"S3_PATH":"s3://test/Image_Scan_Reports/"
"Notification_Topic":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111:Image-notification SNS_TOPIC",
"Base_Image":"python:3.7"
},
{
"ECR_REPO_URL":"1111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
"ECR_REPO_NAME":"test-ecr-repo-1",
"REGION":"us-east-1",
"S3_PATH":"s3://test/Image_Scan_Reports/"
"Notification_Topic":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111:Image-notification SNS_TOPIC",
"Base_Image":"nodejs:alpine"
}
]
```

is that possible? please help me to pass the values to the script.

Answer (score 0):

The *right* answer is to parse with `jq` or some other JSON-aware tool.
Anything else is going to be really messy and error-prone.

...but on the off chance that you have no other option, and with no guarantees, looking ONLY at the specific example given...

You can pipe the above through this -

```
sed -E '/[^[:punct:][:space:]]/!d; s/^[^"]*"([^"]+)"[:[:space:]]*"([^"]+)"[^"]*$/\1="\2"/;'
```

which will give you this -

```
ECR_REPO_URL="111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
ECR_REPO_NAME="test-ecr-repo"
REGION="us-east-1"
S3_PATH="s3://test/Image_Scan_Reports/"
Notification_Topic="arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111:Image-notification SNS_TOPIC"
Base_Image="python:3.7"
ECR_REPO_URL="1111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
ECR_REPO_NAME="test-ecr-repo-1"
REGION="us-east-1"
S3_PATH="s3://test/Image_Scan_Reports/"
Notification_Topic="arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111:Image-notification SNS_TOPIC"
Base_Image="nodejs:alpine"
```

Which can be written to a file and `source`d to load these vars into your code.

I saved your original data as `x`.

```
$: sed -E '/[^[:punct:][:space:]]/!d; s/^[^"]*"([^"]+)"[:[:space:]]*"([^"]+)"[^"]*$/\1="\2"/;' x>|y
$: . y
$: echo $Base_Image
nodejs:alpine
```

But please, don't do this. Get and use the right tool if you possibly can.
This is a hack if for a quick and dirty test, not production code.